# DB2: Insert into with select, incrementing a column for each new row by one for each insert?

Tags: sql, db2

Im trying to copy the contents from a column in one table to another and at the same time want to populate the primary key column with an incrementing number for each row created:

I have tried doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2) VALUES((SELECT col1 FROM table2), (SELECT NEXTVAL FOR col2_SEQ FROM sysibm.sysdummy1));
```

but get the following error:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0348N  "NEXTVAL FOR col2_SEQ" cannot be specified in this 
context.  SQLSTATE=428F
```

It seems that i cant use the sequence value in this way, is there any other way I can achieve what I'm trying to do? I just need col2 in table1 to be populated with a unique BIGINT for each new entry from col1 from table2

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Linux/Unix/Windows (and probably for others), I think you just want [`NEXT VALUE FOR sequence`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023464.html).  You don't need the extra select from sysdummy in this context.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
    SELECT col1, NEXT VALUE FOR col2_SEQ
    FROM table2
```

Comment: NEXT VALUE is for db2 version 9.7!

Comment: @Mo., what platform and version of DB2 are you running?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 methods in which unique values can be generated in DB2.

1. `GENERATE_UNIQUE` function
2. `IDENTITY` column
3. `SEQUENCE` object

Assuming `col2_SEQ` is created similar to below statement:

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE col2_SEQ  
    AS INTEGER  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1  
    NO MINVALUE  
    NO MAXVALUE  
    NO CYCLE  
    ORDER
```

The insert statement can be written as follows:

```
    INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2)
    VALUES ((SELECT col1 FROM table2), 
         NEXT VALUE FOR col2_SEQ)
```

More information, on each of the three methods mentioned above, can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0205pilaka/0205pilaka2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should specify the columns as:

```
col2 smallint not null 
     generated by default as identity (start with 1, increment by 1)
```

and `insert into table1 select col1, default from table2`

Answer (score 0):

There is also alternative syntax now, which worked for me in DB2 10.x

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, schema.seq_name.nextval
FROM table2;
```